# AS3/Flex Decorator Pattern

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, decorator

I'm trying to create a decorator class in AS3/Flex in order to add some functionality to a UI element. The problem is that I don't know how to automatically "redirect" method and property calls to the object being decorated. I suppose I'm looking for something like the __call() "magic method" from PHP, which is called every time the application calls a non-callable method.

So, the question is - how do I redirect calls for methods and properties (which aren't overriden/don't exist in the decorator class) to the object being decorated?

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest to magic methods in actionscript would be extending [Proxy](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/Proxy.html).

Comment: ObjectProxy too maybe http://blogs.adobe.com/cssdk/2010/06/integrating_adobe_creative_suite_cs5_with_other_systems_via_adobe_livecycle_data_services.html